# How to write data into a buffer and write the buffer into a binary file with a second thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, compression, buffer

I am getting data from a sensor(camera) and writing the data into a binary file. The problem is it takes lot of space on the disk.
So, I used the compression from boost (zlib) and the space reduced a lot! The problem is the compression process is slow and lots of data is missing.

So, I want to implement two threads, with one getting the data from the camera and writing the data into a buffer. The second thread will take the front data of the buffer and write it into the binary file. And in this case, all the data will be present.

How do I implement this buffer? It needs to expand dynamically and pop_front. Shall I use std::deque, or does something better already exist?

Comment: Use multiple buffers with a fixed size. Fill up a buffer with the data from the camera. When it's full, pass it off to another thread which a) compresses it, b) writes it to disk, c) frees the buffer. Meanwhile your primary thread is filling another buffer.

Comment: You can use `std::deque`, but have to protect push/pop operations with a mutex.

Comment: Adding a second thread won't make it any faster.

Comment: It wont make it faster but all the data will be present. And when I stop recording, it will keep writing the frames in the file.

Comment: main thread will just write data to a buffer (vector<char>), second thread will poll that buffer every fixed amount of microseconds (50/100 depending on your usage). Second thread will make a copy of the vector on its thread local buffer and compress/save that. 
Thread 1 will be blocked only during the copy, which will be pretty fast, faster than actually writing on disk the full content in your initial scenario.

Comment: by buffer, do you mean a memory buffer? It's soon gonna exhaust your system memory because the consumption goes much slower than feeding.

Comment: Ok, now I have 2 threads. One fill the std::deque<float *> pretty fast. The other one compress and write the float* in a binary file. Right now, it is working, I dont lose any data. But the std::deque will expand pretty fast. I will run out of memory right ?

Comment: You could consider pigz http://zlib.net/pigz/ which is a parallel implementation of gzip. As @EJP mentions a second thread used for making overlapped I/O won't make it any faster. However a parallel implementation of the zipping makes it faster

Comment: All the data will be present either way. I don't see the point.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to consider these four rates (or speeds):

- Speed of Production (**SP**): The average number of bytes your sensor produces per second.
- Speed of Compression (**SC**): The average number of bytes per second you can compress. This is the number of input bytes to the compression algorithm.
- Rate of Compression (**RC**): The average ratio of compressed data to uncompressed data your compress algorithm produces (ratio of size of output to the input of compression.) (This is obviously somewhere between 0 and 1.)
- Speed of Writing (**SW**): The average number of bytes you can write to disk, per second.

If **SC** is less than **SP**, you are in trouble. It means you can't compress all the data you gather from your sensor, in real time. Which means you'll eventually run out of buffer memory. You'll have to find a faster compression algorithm, or dedicate more CPU cores to compression.

If **SW** is less than **SP** times **RC** (which is the size of sensor data after compression,) you are again in trouble. It means you can't write out your output data as fast as you are producing and compressing them, and again, you will eventually run out of buffer memory, no matter how much you have. You might be able to gain some speed by adopting a better write strategy or file system, but a real gain in **SW** comes from a better disk system (RAID, SSD, better hardware, etc.)

Now, if everything is OK speed-wise, you can probably employ something like the following architecture to read, compress and write the data out:

You'll have three threads (or two, described later) that do one part of the pipeline each. You'll also have two **thread-safe queues**, one for communication from each stage of the pipeline to the next.

Assuming the two queues are named `Q1` and `Q2`, the high-level operation of the threads will look like this:

1. Input Thread:

   1. Read `K` bytes of sensor data
   2. Put the whole `K` bytes as a unit on `Q1`.
   3. Go to 1.
2. Compression Thread:

   1. Wait till there is something on `Q1`.
   2. Pop one buffer of data (probably `K` bytes) from `Q1`.
   3. Compress the buffer into a hopefully smaller buffer and put it on `Q2`.
   4. Go to 1.
3. Output Thread:

   1. Wait till there is something on `Q2`.
   2. Pop one buffer of data from `Q2`.
   3. Write the buffer to the output file.
   4. Go to 1.

The most CPU-intensive part of the work is in the second thread, and the other two *probably* don't consume much CPU time and therefore *probably* can share a CPU core. This means that the above strategy may be runnable on two cores. But it can also run on a single core if the workload is light, or require many many cores. That all depends on the four rates I described up top.

Using **asynchronous** writes (e.g. IOCP on Windows or epoll on Linux,) you can drop the third thread and the second queue altogether. Then your second thread needs to execute something like this:

1. Wait till there is something on `Q1`.
2. Pop one buffer of data (probably `K` bytes) from `Q1`.
3. Compress the buffer into a hopefully smaller buffer.
4. Issue an asynchronous write request to the OS to write out the compressed buffer to disk.
5. Go to 1.

There are four more issues worth mentioning:

1. `K` should be selected so that the time required for various (usually constant time) activities associated with allocating a buffer, pushing it into and popping it from a thread-safe queue, starting a compression run and issuing a write request into a file become negligible relative to doing the actual work (reading sensor data, compressing bytes and writing to disk.) This usually means that `K` needs to be as large as possible. But if `K` is very large (many megabytes or hundreds of megabytes) then if your application crashes, you'll lose a lot of data. You need to find a balance between performance and risk of data loss. I suggest (without any knowledge of your specific needs and constraints) a value between 10KiB to 1MiB for `K`.
2. Implementing a thread-safe queue is easy if you have some knowledge and experience with concurrent/parallel programming, but rather hard and error-prone if you do not. Finding good examples and implementations should not be hard. A normal `std::deque` or `std::list` or `std::`anything won't be usable by itself, but can used as a good basis for writing a thread-safe queue.
3. Note that you are queuing *buffers of data*, not individual numbers or bytes. If you pass your data one number at a time through this pipeline, it will be painfully slow and wasteful.
4. Some compression algorithms are limited in how much data they can consume in each invocation, or that you must sync the output of each one call to compression routine with one call to the decompression routine later on. These might affect the choice of `K`, and also how you write your output file. You might have to add some metadata so that you can be able to actually decompress and read the data later.